# How to get the global variable value in Perl?

Tags: perl

Trying to understand scope resolution operator.

```
$a = 5;
foo();
print "Out a = $a\n";

sub foo() {
  local $a = 10;
  bar();
}

sub bar() {
  print "Inside a = $a\n";
  print "Global a = $::a\n";
}
```

Output from this program is :

```
Inside a = 10
Global a = 10
Out a = 5
```

1. I would have expected value of '$::a' to come out as '5' instead of 10. I thought that is what scope resolution operator do. Getting scoped values. In this case, no scope is given, so global value. Please correct me if there is any tweak.
2. What should I write to get the global value of 'a' inside bar subroutine?

Comment: According to [Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) Chapter 4 : *"In addition to global scoping and lexical scoping, we also have what is known as
dynamic scoping, implemented by local, which despite the word “local” really deals with global variables and has nothing to do with the local scratchpad."*

Comment: `local` just makes a temporary backup of a global/package variable. `$a` refers to `$main::a` (since `main` is the current package) absent a `my` or `our` that overrides this. `$::a` is short for `$main::a`. You want `my` instead of `local`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `::`.  Perl doesn't really have global variables (leaving aside certain special identifier names); it has package variables.  That is, every global variable belongs to a package.  If your code has no `package` statement, that package is `main`, so `$a` is the same as `$main::a`.  And having nothing before the `::` is shorthand for `main`, so `$::a` is also `$main::a`.

If you do have a `package` declaration, package variables used within its scope will be contained in that package unless qualified with `::`.

`local` gives a package variable or hash or array element a temporary value and saves the previous value to be restored when the innermost scope is left.
There is no way to access that saved value from within the scope of the local.

The opposite of global/package variables are lexical variables.  You almost always will want to use lexical variables (declared with `my`), not package variables.  Even when you do use package variables, you will hardly ever want to change their value with `local`.  So a good case for using `local` is going to be truly rare.

Comment: Bang on! Clears the misconceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Well, first off - don't use `$a` - single letter variable names are generally nasty, and that goes double for when it's used by `sort`.

Secondly [`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) doesn't do what you think it does. It even says in the man page:

> You really probably want to be using my instead, because local isn't what most people think of as "local". See Private Variables via my() in perlsub for details.
>
> A local modifies the listed variables to be local to the enclosing block, file, or eval. If more than one value is listed, the list must be placed in parentheses. See Temporary Values via local() in perlsub for details, including issues with tied arrays and hashes.

So you *probably* want to use `my`, but... actually, more likely, you probably just want to *not* do that, and don't use globals at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;    
use warnings;

our $number = 5;
foo();
print "Out number = $number\n";

sub foo {
  my $number = 10;
  print "Inside foo: $number\n";
  print "Global foo $::number\n";
  bar();
}

sub bar {
  print "Inside bar = $number\n";
  print "Global $::number\n";
}
```

As you can see - `$number` is lexically scoped to be "within foo" and doesn't persist into b.

```
Inside foo: 10
Global foo = 5
Inside a = 5
Global a = 5
Out number = 5
```

Thirdly - don't use prototypes on your subs. They don't do what you think they do.

Comment: I understand that. To not use $a. :) I see about the example which you gave. Make sense. But then what I wrote is a valid syntax. What should we do to get 2nd point in this case.

Comment: @HemantBhargava You cannot access the previous global value until you exit the local scope

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Oops! This is not what I expected. Perl design problem? There should be some way to access the global value. Right?

Comment: @HemantBhargava I don't think it is a design problem. If you want access to the previous global value, you could store it away before issuing the `local` command.

Comment: The question is - why do you have a lexically scoped variable that's masking a global in the first place? This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)